# MySql server recipe in Chef does not set specified password

Tags: mysql, chef-infra

I am trying to run the mysql::server recipe at a CentOS 6.2 machine using chef-solo. 
The installation runs fine, but the password that I set in the attribute node['mysql']['server_root_password'] does not work.
I always get an error when mysql-install-privileges is about to run and a I can't access the mysql server as well, with or withtout the password I specified.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you log into the mysql server using the monitor or other mysql tools?

Comment: I tried with mysql workbench and that did not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with $$ caracters. Once I changed it to another thing it worked!

Answer (score 0):

open your MySQL console and login as root or SU.

```
update mysql.user set password=password('your_password') where user='username';
```

only if you are 100% that the user is there and the privileges too, if you need to create user and grant access that's another thing

Comment: I can't connect to the mysql console as root, that is the problem.

Comment: can you login the chef login and pass?

Comment: what chef login and pass? I am using chef-solo

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. I found that if you don't set the attribute `node["mysql"]["server_root_password"]` at the normal level, then it doesn't stick. I fixed it by putting the following in the default attribute file of my wrapper cookbook:

In chef-repo/WRAPPERCOOKBOOK/attributes/default.rb

```
node.normal["mysql"]["server_root_password"] = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
```